# Runtime error when category is added to the UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uiwebview, categories

## Description

I just add a category `UIWebView+CategoryTest` to `UIWebView`, which swizzling it's `layoutSubviews` with a custom method `hlz_layoutSubviews`, but the `UIWebView` never used in my project. When I build and run the application, a runtime error shows up when excuting `[self hlz_layoutSubviews];`

> CategoryTest[29881:2122091] -[UIWindow hlz_layoutSubviews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8e73d311e0

Am I missing something?

## Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create an empty project using `Single View Application` template in Xcode.
2. Add a new category `UIWebView+CategoryTest` to `UIWebView`.
3. Replace the code in `UIWebView+CategoryTest.m` with followings:

```

```
@implementation UIWebView (CategoryTest)

+ (void)load {
    // Swizzle the `layoutSubviews` method.
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(layoutSubviews));
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(hlz_layoutSubviews));

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    });
}

- (void)hlz_layoutSubviews {
    [self hlz_layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

```

4. Add `Exception Breakpoint` for `All Exceptions` in the `Breakpoint navigator`.
5. Build and run the demo application.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussing with other developers, Turns out the reason is that the method `layoutSubviews` I have swizzled out in UIWebView is implemented by it's superclass `UIView`. So the exchange of the methods also affects other subclass of UIView, such as `UIWindow`. As a result, When `layoutSubviews` is sent to the instance of `UIWindow`, the swizzled `hlz_layoutSubviews` is actually sent to it.